# Quick question on comparing two probabilities of an event

Tags: probability, fractions

Quick Question on probability.

does $P(a)= \frac{\#a-1}{99}$ mean there is a lesser chance of 'a' occuring when compared to $P(a)= \frac{\#a-2}{98}$ ?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n-1}{99} \lt \frac{n-2}{98} \iff n \gt 100 \iff \frac{n-1}{99} \gt 1$

Comment: I'm the most lay of laypeople sorry. Just to clarify, that means 'a' is more likely when $P(a)= \frac{\#a-2}{98}$ compared to when $P(a)= \frac{\#a-1}{99}$ correct?

Comment: Hint: which fraction is smaller? (Yes.)